# Como usar o PDO e PHP para Mostrar em Tabela Dado de Pesquisa

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Estou com uma dúvida. Não entendo o motivo do meu código não estar correto. Por favor, se puderem revisá-lo, ficaria bem feliz.

```
<?php
    require_once "db_connect.php";

    //conectar banco
    $conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;bancodedados=$bancodedados", 
    $usuario, $senha);

    if(isset($_POST['nomeProduto'])){
        $nomeProduto = $_POST['nomeProduto'];
        $query = $conectar->prepare("SELECT * FROM nilo_db.nilo_tb
        WHERE nomeProduto LIKE ?");
        $query->execute(array($nomeProduto));
        if($query->rowCount() == 0){
            while($linha = $query->fetch()){ ?>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td><?php echo $linha['nomeProduto']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['categoriaProduto']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['codigoProduto']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['fornecedor']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['emEstoque']; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php       }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: `bancodedados=$bancodedados` não seria `dbname=algo....` ?

Comment: Então, a conexão ela está funcionando corretamente, pois com o insert está dando certo. É que eu nomeei o banco de dados de "bancodedados" mesmo.

Comment: Se esse não problema, então deve ser no `LIKE` vc não vai passar os `%` ? pode coloca eles junto no `execute()`. Você poderia descrever melhor qual é o problema ou sintoma do código, batendo o olho essas foram as coisas que vi 'fora do padrão'.